# Use the processing power of Hadoop cluster rather than the GNU/Linux machine

Tags: linux, hadoop, diff

I am doing a diff between 2 files located on Hadoop cluster.
diff <(hcat file1) <(hcat file2)
The challenge is the files are >10GB in size.
If we want to diff of 100 such files simultaneously then the processing power of the GNU/Linux machine takes a hit.
Is there a way we could use the processing power of the Hadoop cluster to do a diff of such large sized files simultaneously?

Comment: Hadoop uses **shared nothing** architecture which means that all records are processed independently. In your case it will mean that HDFS block size should be at least **20GB** (64-128 MB default). So, it's crazy to use Hadoop in this case ;)

Comment: I get your point. :)
Anything with mapred where we can use 2 mappers(1 mapper to read each file) and 1 reducer (to run the diff). ?

Comment: Just a clarification. I think you have misunderstood something, but maybe I'm wrong. Hadoop is not a cluster or an OS. It is an implementation of Map/Reduce programming model that you can use to have parallel processing of an algorithm that you provide (different than the sequential algorithm). It can also run on Linux machines.

Comment: MapRed is just 1 of the 4 modules of Hadoop.
Others being Hadoop Common, HDFS and Hadoop Yarn.
HDFS(Hadoop Distributed File System) is a distributed file-system that stores data on commodity machines, providing very high aggregate bandwidth across the cluster.

Comment: At a high level, you'll need to write a custom distributed differ.  You'll have to split your files into chunks and ship pairs of chunks to individual nodes to do the diffing.  You should be able to leverage YARN to do this, but MapReduce may not be the best fit.

If you want your differ to be fast, you'd implement it such every chunk is only compared with one or two chunks from the other file.  If you want to do a comprehensive diff, you'll have to compare every chunk with *every* chunk from the other file.